# i need to Merging half of strings using gets and puts

Tags: c, string, gets, puts

Write a program that reads two strings CH1 and CH2 and copies the first half of CH1 and the first half of CH2 into a third CH3 string. Display the result Using the **gets** and **puts** functions.

the output shoud be like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7cuZ.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Where is this task from? Some assignment/homework? Please explain what you have tried so far, show some code etc. We cannot solve a whole task for you. Stackoverflow is there to answer questions, so please explain what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char CH1[20] , CH2[20] , eCH1[20] , eCH2[20] ; // I used e for exit string 
int i , j ;
printf("Enter first string:");
gets(CH1);
printf("Enter second string:");
gets(CH2);
i = strlen(CH1);
j = strlen(CH2);
strncpy(eCH1 , CH1 , i/2);
strncpy(eCH2 , CH2 , j/2);
strcat(eCH1 , eCH2);
printf("The half of first string + The half of second string :%s", eCH1);

return 0;
}
```